# How can I add a new colon-command to Evil?

Tags: customize, evil

`evil-mode` introduces vim-style colon commands (such as `:wq` to save and close).

I have a few commands (such as `kill-buffer`, `org-babel-tangle`) that I'd like to be able to run through this instead of the keybindings they currently have.

How can I add colon-commands like `:k` for `kill-buffer` and `:tangle` for `org-babel-tangle`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The official way of doing this is demonstrated in `evil-maps.el`.

Therefore, creating a new ex command is very simple:

```
(evil-ex-define-cmd "b[utterfly]" 'butterfly)
```

You'll want to either use this after enabling Evil or alternatively after loading the respective file:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-ex
  '(evil-ex-define-cmd "b[utterfly]" 'butterfly))
```

Doing this will modify `evil-ex-commands` appropriately.

Comment: Excellent! I had tried finding that but didn't succeed (obviously)

Comment: _I got that reference!_